# Does Android support the external USB devices?

Tags: usb, keyboard, camera

Does Android support the external USB devices like PC keyboard, joystick, camera or other devices that can be connected to the PC? If so, then do I need some additional software, or is it enough to connect external device via Standard/Micro USB adapter?

Comment: Depends very much on Android OS version, and the hardware included in the device (you can find out by looking for specifications and manuals for your specific device's manufacturer and model number).  Please add this information to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that depends on your device, which must support this as well. Android itself does support this since [3.1-honeycomb](/questions/tagged/3.1-honeycomb) – and I e.g. successfully use an external keyboard with my tablets, which is just plugged into the USB port.

The keyword to look for is [usb-on-the-go](/questions/tagged/usb-on-the-go). We already have [more than 60 posts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-on-the-go) on this topic, which you might wish to check (or start with the [9 most frequented](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-on-the-go?sort=frequent) to easier get to the core points). If those leave open questions, feel free to ask those in separate posts :)

**Edit:** As Dan correctly points out in his comment, if your device has a full-sized USB port, there's no need for OTG. See our [usb-host-mode](/questions/tagged/usb-host-mode) tag for that.

Comment: You don't necessarily need USB-OTG: some Android devices have a normal (full-size) USB port for connecting peripherals to. Use the [tag:usb-host-mode] tag, which applies in either case.